# в раскладке с недавнего времени не отображаются окна

Tags: xcode

xcode в раскладке с недавнего времени не отображаются окна, только переходы 
При этом на симуляторе и устройстве все отображается [image: раскладка]

Comment: открывала сториборд в новом окне, в данный момент все работает в обычном режиме